# How to fill an L path with a reflected gradient?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I'm trying to make an L shape where the gradient would go from the edge of the path to the center. In the image currently, I have 5 squares (ignoring the white squares) with a reflected gradient. The issue in this image is the corner. I'm not sure how I can seamlessly connect it to its neighbor. Any ideas?

[image: Gradient example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you draw your L as a single shape or stroked path, not separate pieces, then you could use a Stroke layer style using a gradient,set the position to Inside, and the style set to Shape Burst, and make the size big enough to cover the hole in the middle.

An example

[image]Click to view larger

If you don't want the gradient to extend to the ends of the L, you could cover over the ends with black rectangles on a new layer, or white squares if you prefer.

[image]

Comment: Thank worked great! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- fill with black a L-shaped selection on an otherwise empty layer. As well you can draw a vector shape.
- give to it layer style "inner glow"
- tweak the contour curve and other settings for the wanted edge and gradient

An example

[image]

Insert the white squares to a new layer if you need them

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly you have already got 2 tricky suggestions. But the next 15 seconds edit is made to your screenshot:

[image]

There's a triangular selection over the problem area. It's drawn with the polygonal lasso. Simply take the patch tool and move it upwards from the selection. This is the result.